# How to restart clip from the beginning after stopping it?

Tags: java, audio

```
Clip clip;
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound));
```

I mean, how to start playing clip always from the beginning. When I stop it in the middle and then start it again, it plays from the middle and that's what I do not want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0)` before playing the clip again. This will reset the current position.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#setMicrosecondPosition(long)